# iOS Pusher client not automatically reconnecting

Tags: ios, swift, pusher

I'm using the Pusher client for iOS, installing it via CocoaPods (`pod 'libPusher', '~> 1.5'`).

It all sets up fine and the events come through fine. However if the device (iPhone 6s running iOS 9.0.2) loses the internet connection (caused by me going to airplane mode) then regains it a minute later (me coming out of airplane mode), Pusher never regains a connection.

I've added a some UIAlertViews to test out what it's doing based on it's delegate method.

Initially `connectionWillConnect` and `connectionDidConnect` are shown.

When airplane mode is turned on `connectionWillConnect` then `connectionWillAutomaticallyReconnection afterDelay of 0.0` are shown.

(Then left for a minute or so without the internet.)

Then nothing, even after connection back to the internet. And the events are no longer received properly.

-

Here is the class I use for all the Pusher things (written in Swift 2.0), which works well until connection is lost.

```
class PusherInterface: NSObject, PTPusherDelegate {

    // MARK: - PusherInterface Shared Instance

    /// Singleton instance of the PusherInterface class.
    private static let sharedInstance = PusherInterface()


    // MARK: - Pusher Credentials

    private static let pusherAppId = "MY_APP_ID"
    private static let pusherKey = "MY_KEY"
    private static let pusherSecret = "MY_SECRET"

    /// The connected client used by Pusher to connect to event channels
    private static var client: PTPusher = {
        let pusherClient = PTPusher.pusherWithKey(pusherKey, delegate: PusherInterface.sharedInstance)
        pusherClient.connect()
        return pusherClient as! PTPusher
        }()


    // MARK: - Setup Pusher

    static func startListening() {
        client.subscribeToChannelNamed("MY_CHANNEL")

        client.bindToEventNamed("MY_EVENT") { pusherEvent in
            // Does some stuff with the data back
        }
    }


    // MARK: - Pusher Delegate

    func pusher(pusher: PTPusher!, connectionDidConnect connection: PTPusherConnection!) {
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
            UIAlertView(title: "connectionDidConnect", message: "", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Dismiss").show()
        }
    }

    func pusher(pusher: PTPusher!, connectionWillAutomaticallyReconnect connection: PTPusherConnection!, afterDelay delay: NSTimeInterval) -> Bool {
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
            UIAlertView(title: "connectionWillAutomaticallyReconnect", message: "afterDelay \(delay)", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Dismiss").show()
        }

        return true
    }

    func pusher(pusher: PTPusher!, connectionWillConnect connection: PTPusherConnection!) -> Bool {
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
            UIAlertView(title: "connectionWillConnect", message: "", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Dismiss").show()
        }

        return true
    }

}
```

Any ideas on why it's not working?

All ideas & theories would be very much appreciated! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't working for me either with Swift. I installed a [swift implementation](https://github.com/pusher-community/pusher-websocket-swift) of Pusher and is working fine now.

```
    let pusher = Pusher(key: "c984997151153c177dc2")
    pusher.connect()

    let channel = pusher.subscribe("test_channel")
    channel.bind("my_event") { (event: AnyObject?) -> Void in
        print("my_event push received ")
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't work for us, we connected Pusher while inside app, we stayed in app and disconnected from internet, so Pusher disconnected also and then we connected on internet but Pusher remained disconeccted